# How would one show that $\textbf{Z}$ is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that the set of all integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed countable which would mean that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}|$.

This would further imply that I have to find a bijection between the two sets, but I do not really know how to do that.

I have tried with a function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that all the odd numbers are mapped to the positive subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, and all even numbers are mapped to the negative numbers.

I think that this will produce a valid solution but I don't have the details yet, and I also do not really know how to account for zero in all of this.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: $0, -1, 1, -2,2, -3,3,...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a set is countable, you literally count the elements in some order

$$0_1,-1_2,1_3,-2_4,2_5,-3_6,3_7,-4_8,4_9,\cdots$$

without omission.

It is an easy matter to show that for all $m\ge 0$,  $m$ comes $2m+1^{th}$ and $-m$ comes $2m^{th}$.

---

**Technical note:**

A counting scheme where the same elements are counted more than once is acceptable, because you can in principle renumber to skip the duplicates and restore a bijection. But all element must be counted at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible bijection (likely similar to one you were thinking of) would be:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac n2 &\text{$n$ is even}\\
-\frac {n+1}{2}\quad &\text{$n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$